# How to define UITableViewCellStyle after init?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have the following code for my custom cell:

```
ENSCustomCell *cell = (ENSCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[ENSCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSDictionary *ens;
ens = [ensList objectAtIndex:row];

NSDictionary *toDic = [ens objectForKey:@"an"];
NSString *toString = @"";
NSInteger count = 0;
for (NSDictionary *str in toDic)
{
    count++;
    toString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", toString, [str objectForKey:@"username"]];
    if (count != toDic.count)
    {
        toString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", toString, @", "];
    }

}
[cell setDataWithTitle:toString andSubject:[ens objectForKey:@"betreff"]];
return cell;
```

How to set the right arrow (UITableViewCellStyle) after the init?
Is there a property or method (else then the initWithTyle) for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you're trying to set the right arrow, you're probably looking to change the accessory of the cell rather than the entire cell style. Use the cell's `accessoryType` property:

```
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
```